# Is there any delay in Google Calendar API v3 before deleted calendar actually becomes visible as deleted?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I have [accidentally deleted my whole calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170683/21486). Using Calendar API v3 I wanted to:

- Get it back
- Get as much data as I can or
- Get as much events out of it as I can

(with the method [described by Google Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/7143502/i-accidentally-deleted-an-entire-calendar-how-can-i-restore-it-it-hasn-t-ever-been-backed-up?hl=en)).

But when I [call to *Calendar API's*.`CalendarList: list` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.calendarList.list) with `showDeleted` set to `true`:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?showDeleted=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

[image]

Then:

- I *can* easily *see* a calendar **deleted half a year ago** but
- I *cannot see* a calendar deleted **half an hour ago**

What am I missing?

Is there any *magical period of time* after deleted calendars (or data in general) becomes available through Calendar API? Or maybe there are some specific types of calendars that never appears (are accessible) through Calendar API?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the deletion hasn't fully propagated through Google's servers yet. While it's not explicitly stated in the documentation, it's reasonable to assume that there might be a delay in synchronization.

As for the types of calendars, as long as the calendar was on your CalendarList, it should appear with **showDeleted=true**, regardless of the calendar type.

Lastly, ensure that you're using the correct authorization scopes and that your access token is still valid. Also, if you are handling multiple accounts, verify you're looking at the correct account's CalendarList.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR;

The entire answer below is based on speculations. We cannot rule them out, as we do not have access to source code of Google services. The answer is also a little bit emotional. But my observations seem to be firm arguments supporting my theory.

### Situation one (Wednesday)

1. I deleted the *calendar W* by accident. I hit the net, Google says "cannot be undone", while providing at the same time [an API that allows you to read all calendars including the deleted ones as well](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix_params=%7B%22showDeleted%22%3Atrue%7D)
2. I opened this page, I made myself sure that `showDeleted` = `true` and I ran the request
3. It returned two calendars (two IDs), one with a name (in a separate field), the other without a name
4. The name of the first calendar (let us call it *calendar S*) clearly suggests that it is a calen-dar removed at least 4-5 months ago. The second calendar had no name, so at this moment I have no clue if that is the accidentally deleted *calendar W*.
5. Having two calendar IDs, I ran a second request -- the one that [returns all events from the calendar with the given `calendarID`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list?apix_params=%7B%22calendar-Id%22%3A%222br6br362jfn24cg6bqurf5fi7ok%40group.calendar.google.com%22%2C%22showDeleted%22%3Atrue%7D).
6. Effects:

- Calendar removed almost half a year ago nicely returns all 500+ events
- A calendar deleted half an hour ago returns a 404.

### Situation two (Saturday)

1. I ran [the first request](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix_params=%7B%22showDeleted%22%3Atrue%7D) again and this time I had the ID of... one calendar, the one deleted four days ago. No trace of the second.
2. I ran [the second request](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list?apix_params=%7B%22calendar-Id%22%3A%222br6br362jfn24cg6bqurf5fi7ok%40group.calendar.google.com%22%2C%22showDeleted%22%3Atrue%7D) with the first (the only) calendar ID and I had a 404 again.

### Conclusions

Now call me an idiot but this is how I see it:

1. Google Calendar team must consist of at least one moron, who deliberately has not imple-mented the bluntly important functionality of getting (an accidentally) deleted calendar back.
2. The amount of data that a deleted calendar stores are a microscopic bacterium compared to the ocean of Google data, so the issue of lack of space in server rooms is not an argument here.
3. The number of people who want to undo the deletion of the calendar is negligible, the traffic generated by such queries fades in the background of traffic noise, so the issue of loading Google servers is not an argument either.
4. Deleted events, i.e., those that generate the actual size of the calendar, are stored for regular calendars (because the Undo function works), so deleting them for deleted calendars is a mis-understanding.
5. Nowadays, no one ever deletes anything permanently, the `isDeleted` flag is switched and that is all. All the data in the world is stored indefinitely. If not for anything else, then for sure for legal reasons at least (a court case sometime in the future)
6. The knowledge that nobody is deleting anything today) is so obvious that only the fact that the sun is shining is more obvious. Therefore, permanently deleting data by Google is either insanity or a false claim.
7. Google's infrastructure and architecture is wrong that they can "forget" to delete calendar’s data and keep it for months, despite Google's claim that it is impossible to recover a deleted calendar.
8. **The best one**. One of my deleted calendars remained available through API for months and suddenly "disappeared" when I queried that API about it. A coincidence? I do not think so.
9. I have got a suggestion ([Ajil T U's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76316687/1469208) that the fact that I see the calendar delet-ed half a year ago and I don't see the calendar deleted half an hour ago may be due to the fact that the data did not fully propagate through the infrastructure Google.

Fortunately, Google has already solved this problem for me. Data from both deleted calendars is currently unavailable. The only caveat is that one calendar was deleted "partially" (the list of calendars still returns it, but the list of events generates a 404), and the other was deleted "completely" (the list of calendars does not return calendar's ID at).

### Summary

1. It is not possible to revert calendar deletion at all, neither clicking through the interface nor by calling an API
2. There is no gap or delay in Google Calendar API v3 before deleted calendar becomes visible as deleted (as asked in the question). If anyone sees any deleted calendar, events out of it, any piece of it through API then one can certainly treat that as a Google garbage.